# Is there a cleaner way to compose SBT tasks?

Tags: scala, sbt

There is a useful SBT plugin for formatting license headers:
https://github.com/Banno/sbt-license-plugin

As of 0.1.0, it only formats "scalaSource in Compile":

```
object Plugin extends sbt.Plugin {
  import LicenseKeys._

  object LicenseKeys {  
    lazy val formatLicenseHeaders = TaskKey[Unit]("formatLicenseHeaders", "Includes the license header to source files")
    …
  }

  def licenseSettings = Seq(
    formatLicenseHeaders <<= formatLicenseHeadersTask,
    …
  )

  …

  private def formatLicenseHeadersTask = 
    (streams, scalaSource in Compile, license in formatLicenseHeaders, removeExistingHeaderBlock in formatLicenseHeaders) map {
      (out, sourceDir, lic, removeHeader) =>
        modifySources(sourceDir, lic, removeHeader, out.log)
    }
```

I wrote a pull request where I generalized this to format both java and scala sources used for both compilation and testing here:

https://github.com/Banno/sbt-license-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/license/plugin.scala

```
private def formatLicenseHeadersTask = Def.task[Unit] {
  formatLicenseHeadersTask1.value
  formatLicenseHeadersTask2.value
  formatLicenseHeadersTask3.value
  formatLicenseHeadersTask4.value
}
```

The tasks formatLicenseHeadersTask1234 correspond to the combinations of {scala,java}Source and {Compile,Test}.

This works but it's really ugly. Is there a way to write the same thing with loops as sketched below?

```
for { 
   src <- Seq( scalaSource, javaSource )
   kind <- Seq( Compile, Test )
   …
}
```